# combine multiple numpy ndarrays as list

Tags: arrays, numpy, combinations

I have three equally dimensioned numpy arrays.

I would like to store the data from all three in an array of the same dimensions and size.
To do this, I would like to store three bytes of information per item in the array. I assume this would be a list.

e.g.

```
>>>red = np.array([[150,25],[37,214]])
>>>green = np.array([[190,27],[123,231]])
>>>blue = np.array([[10,112],[123,119]])
```

insert combination magic to make a combined array called RGB

```
>>>RGB
array([(150,190,10),(25,27,112)],[(37,123,123),(214,231,119)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, each is 2x2.  Combined in a list with `array`, same construction as in making `red`, produces a 3x2x2.

```
In [344]: red = np.array([[150,25],[37,214]])
In [345]: green = np.array([[190,27],[123,231]])
In [346]: blue = np.array([[10,112],[123,119]])
In [347]: np.array([red,green,blue])
Out[347]: 
array([[[150,  25],
        [ 37, 214]],

       [[190,  27],
        [123, 231]],

       [[ 10, 112],
        [123, 119]]])
In [348]: _.shape
Out[348]: (3, 2, 2)
```

That's not the order you want, but we can easily reshape, and if needed transpose.

The target, with an added set of []

```
In [350]: np.array([[(150,190,10),(25,27,112)],[(37,123,123),(214,231,119)]])
Out[350]: 
array([[[150, 190,  10],
        [ 25,  27, 112]],

       [[ 37, 123, 123],
        [214, 231, 119]]])
In [351]: _.shape
Out[351]: (2, 2, 3)
```

so try moving the `3` shape to the end with `transpose`:

```
In [352]: np.array([red,green,blue]).transpose(1,2,0)
Out[352]: 
array([[[150, 190,  10],
        [ 25,  27, 112]],

       [[ 37, 123, 123],
        [214, 231, 119]]])
```

===========================

I should have suggested `stack`.  This a newish version of `concatenate` that lets us join arrays on different new dimensions.  With `axis=0` it behaves like `np.array`.  But to join on the last, to put the `rgb` dimension last use:

```
In [467]: np.stack((red,green,blue),axis=-1)
Out[467]: 
array([[[150, 190,  10],
        [ 25,  27, 112]],

       [[ 37, 123, 123],
        [214, 231, 119]]])
In [468]: _.shape
Out[468]: (2, 2, 3)
```

Note that this expression does not assume anything about the shape of `red`, etc, except that they are equal.  So it will work with 3d arrays as well.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, that sounds good. What would you use to combine a red, green and blue array if they have a third dimension, that is, if they are 2x2x2 to begin with?

Comment: I added an example with `np.stack` that should work with 3d arrays as well.

Comment: brillant hpaulj, you are a legend!

Comment: hpaulj: how would you do the reverse? I tried split, but it isn't working the way I would hope. If I split on the -1 axis, I get zillions of 3-int length arrays. I want 3 arrays with zillions of ints. :)

Comment: actually, I think I worked it out with: split_array = np.asarray(np.split(input24bitarray,3, axis = -1))         single_channel = split_array[0]